# How to pause code so it can finish other code and then resume

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dllimport

I want am making an AI and make it just like a player. When it does not know what to do it will do a random move and I called this `rndPlay();` It will randomly choose a location to click. It can choose from 9 locations. `press1();`, `press2();` etc. I make it repeat until it pressed two buttons in a row. Now here is the problem

When the for loop is executing I tell it to press on 850, 400 there is a button there so let's call that `btn1` and that executes `btnPressed1();`, for example, I see the mouse move there and it clicks but it does not execute `btnPressed1();`. Instead, it clicks on the next random location and keeps repeating 10000 times because it did not do a successful move(it has to press two things in a certain order). Then when it exits the for loop it executes `btnPressed1();`. I do not want it to do this after it stops because ontop of every button is another button lets call it `btnMove1` with the number corresponding with the button under it. for example, It had pressed button 1, 1 and 8, it should after pressing `btn1` show `btnMove1` but since it does not execute instantly it presses `btn1` again (not `btnMove1`) and then `btn8` then when it finishes it executes `btnPressed1();` then `btnPressed1();` again and finally `btnPressed8();` How do I make it execute the code it pressed before pressing the next thing?

I have tried to use `Thread.Sleep(100)` to make it stop but it just waits and does not execute the button it just pressed. I also made my own for loop with if statement because I thought it might be the for loop that stops the input from being executed.

XAML code:

```
<button x:Name="btn1" Click="btnPressed1"/>
<button x:Name="btnMove1" Click="btnMove1" Visibility="Hidden"/>
<button x:Name="btn2" Click="btnPressed2"/>
<button x:Name="btnMove2" Click="btnPressedMove2" Visibility="Hidden"/>
<button x:Name="btn3" Click="btnPressed3"/>
<button x:Name="btnMove3" Click="btnMove3" Visibility="Hidden"/>
//etc
```

C# code:

```
        private void btnPressed1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnMove1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
        }

        private void btnPressed2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnMove2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
        }

        //etc

        private void btnPressedMove1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          //some code
        }

        private void btnPressedMove2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          //some code
        }

        //etc

        private void MoveTo(int x, int y)
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y, 0, 0);
        }

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
        //Mouse actions
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private extern bool SetCursorPos(uint X, uint Y);
        private void LeftMouseClick(uint X, uint Y)
        {
            SetCursorPos(X, Y);
            //Call the imported function with the cursor's current 
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return;
        }

        private void press1()
        {
            LeftMouseClick(28000, 25000);
            last2Moves("1");
        }
        private void press2()
        {
            LeftMouseClick(33000, 25000);
            last2Moves("2");
        }
        //etc

        private void rndPlay()
        {
            for (int r = 0; moveSucces != true && r < 10000; r++)
            {

                Random rndP = new Random();
                int rndPress = rndP.Next(1, 10);
                if (rndPress == 1)
                {
                    press1();
                }
                if (rndPress == 2)
                {
                    press2();
                }
                    //etc
             }
         }
```

I want it to first execute `btnPressed1();` before pressing the next button but it saves the things it presses until it finishes the code. How do I make it finish the code before it pressed the next thing?

Comment: Everything is executing properly. You just can't see it because  you have frozen the UI by doing this long running loop on the UI thread. The UI thread is busy executing the loop and cannot update the UI, hence the freeze. Solution is to execute the loop asynchronously.

Comment: Microsoft Docs: [CPU-bound Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async#cpu-bound-example-performing-a-calculation-for-a-game)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications that have a GUI are event driven. All user actions (and some other events) are posted to a message queue and handled one by one by the message loop. You can read this for some background information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues

If you write code like your for loop that takes a long time to execute, then you are blocking this message loop from handling any events.

One way you can avoid blocking the message loop is by rewriting rndPlay as an async method:

```
    private async Task rndPlay()
    {
        for (int r = 0; moveSucces != true && r < 10000; r++)
        {

            Random rndP = new Random();
            int rndPress = rndP.Next(1, 10);
            if (rndPress == 1)
            {
                press1();
            }
            if (rndPress == 2)
            {
                press2();
            }
            //etc

            await Task.Delay(1000);
         }
     }
```

This has the effect of pausing the execution of `rndPlay` at each `await`, and posting the continuation of the method execution to the message queue after a 1000ms delay. That way, other events on the message queue get a chance of getting processed by the message loop.

Note that your example code doesn't show the caller of `rndPlay`. You might have to make some changes there also.

Comment: MSDN states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) : `do not rely on await Task.Yield(); to keep a UI responsive`, but i agree that async programming may be a good starting point.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of that. I'm not sure why Task.Yield() wouldn't work, but if it doesn't then I guess Task.Delay(1) might do the trick. Comment added in code example.

Comment: Changed to await Task.Delay(1000) to match the intention of the Thread.Sleep calls in the example.

Comment: 1 second waiting time is too much. Consider this loops runs at least 10,000 times. This is ~10,000 seconds spent just waiting. You should execute the loop on a background thread using `Task.Run` and let the UI thread handle the rest by using the `Dispatcher` to update the UI controls. This will be far more efficient.

Comment: @BionicCode OP is implementing a program with a GUI that is clicking its own buttons by controlling the mouse cursor, which doesn't really make sense in the first place. I think the goal is not speed but just the fun of seeing a program manipulate itself, like the [most useless machine ever](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z86V_ICUCD4) contraption.

Comment: The y way you summarized it makes the question sound really crazy.  Really funny. To the point - I had a good laughter, thank you. Nevertheless,  I think you should provide a sensible solution for the sake of quality. Your current code would take approximately three hours to complete. That's quite funny too. I mean, this will keep him busy watching the buttons pressing itself for quite a while. By the way, I enjoyed your video. An engineering masterpiece. [I liked this quite sophisticated one too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQ9gs-5lRKc).